# Jest: SVG require causes "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

Not sure where to look for this error.

Using Typescript with React, and Jest and Enzyme for unit testing.

Package.json sample:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "bundle": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "json"
    ]
  }
```

Running npm test results in:

```
FAIL src/components/Component.test.tsx

 ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                                                                                             ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Edit: It appears to be happening the first place where i use `require` to load a static `.svg` file. Why can it not handle that? Is there a way to ignore throwing this error when using require?

Comment: Try removing `xml` tag and only include following `svg` tag

Comment: Gawd Jest is so annoying

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Jest doesn't use Webpack so it doesn't know how to load other file extensions than js/jsx. To add support for other extensions you need to write custom transformers. One of the transformers is a Typescript transformer which you have defined in your configuration in this fragment:

```
"transform": {
   "^.+\\.tsx?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
},
```

Now you need to add transformer for svg files. Let's extend your jest config

```
"transform": {
       "^.+\\.tsx?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js",
       "^.+\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/svgTransform.js" 
    },
```

and create the svgTransform.js file in your root directory with the following content

```
module.exports = {
  process() {
    return { code: 'module.exports = {};' };
  },
  getCacheKey() {
    // The output is always the same.
    return 'svgTransform';
  },
};
```

Of course, it's a basic transformer that returns always the same value.

Link to the documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object

Comment: no problem! I deleted my comment because you fixed it

Comment: I dont have the preprocessor.js file in react testing library, how does it look like?

Answer (score 10):

If you have used the @svgr/webpack module to allow webpack to handle importing svgs @svgr provides a page that goes over how to handle testing with Jest. [Resource Here](https://react-svgr.com/docs/jest/)

Copied for posterity.

`/__mocks__/svgrMock.js`

```js
import * as React from 'react'
export default 'SvgrURL'
export const ReactComponent = 'div'
```

In `package.json`

```json
"jest": {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.svg": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/svgrMock.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the npm package `jest-transform-stub`

In the Jest config file, add a transform like this:

```
"transform": {
  ...
  "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-transform-stub",
  ...
}

Same transform can be use for any asset file.
  ".+\\.(css|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|gif|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)$": "jest-transform-stub",
```

Answer (score 1):

1. mock your SVG's with something like the following `__mocks__/svgMock.js` file:

```
import React from "react";
export default "SvgURL";
export const ReactComponent = ({ width, height }) => (
  <div>
    w-{width} h-{height}
  </div>
);
```

2. tell Jest where to find this SVG mocker by modifying the jest.config.js with the following property:

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.svg": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/svgMock.js",
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your `jest.config.js` file in the root directory

Add this line inside the `transform` object:

```
 '^.+\\.svg$': './svgTransform.js'
```

so your `jest.config.js` will look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  rootDir: '.',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(j|t)sx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.svg$': './svgTransform.js',
  },
//...
}
```

Then create a file named `svgTransform.js` in the root directory with this content:

```
module.exports = {
  process() {
    return 'module.exports = {};'
  },
  getCacheKey() {
    // The output is always the same.
    return 'svgTransform'
  },
}
```

If you were running your tests in watch mode, be sure to completely stop your test suite and restart it.