# Jest cannot load svg file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, jestjs

In my app I use React and TypeScript. I tried to run jest tests I get following error:

> ```
> C:\Users\e-KDKK\workspace\konrad\mikskarpety\src\images\icons\Sock.svg:1
> ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18.725" height="23.947" viewBox="0 0 18.725 23.947">
>                                                                                          ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>
>   1 | import React, { FC } from 'react';
>   2 | 
> > 3 | import SockIcon from '../../images/icons/Sock.svg';
>     | ^
>   4 | 
>   5 | export const Spinner: FC = () => {
>   6 |   return (
>
>   at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
>   at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Spinner/Spinner.tsx:3:1)
> ```

This file is not even tested. I don't know why it tries to compile it. My `jest.config.json` file contains only coverage thresholds.

I read that jest sometimes needs additional transform section for specific files like SVG, but when I added to configuration

```
"transform": {
    "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-svg-transformer"
},
```

my error message changed only to:

> C:\Users\e-KDKK\workspace\konrad\mikskarpety\test\utils\debounce.test.ts:1
>       ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import
>   { getVersion } from 'jest';
>                                                                                                       ^
>
> ```
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>
>   at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
>   at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
> ```

Which is even more confusing to me.

The code for the app you can find here: https://github.com/KonradKlimczak/mikskarpety

Answer (score 59):

jest doesn't know how to load other file extensions than js/jsx,you need to find the  ***jest.config.js*** and add transformer for svg files.

```
"transform": {
   "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
   "^.+\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/svgTransform.js"
},
```

and create the `svgTransform.js` file (*see [Custom transformers](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react#custom-transformers)*) in your root directory with the following content:

```
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603201/jest-cannot-load-svg-file
module.exports = {
  process() {
    return {
      code: `module.exports = {};`,
    };
  },
  getCacheKey() {
    // The output is always the same.
    return "svgTransform";
  },
};
```

link: https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation#examples

Note [this is the updated syntax for jest 28](https://jestjs.io/docs/28.x/upgrading-to-jest28#transformer).

Comment: This is a straight copy paste of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46810154/3550183

Comment: This doesn't seem to work presently. Same error message

Comment: I am using svg inside tsx file and it doesn't work since the above config is referring directly to svg only so my code is basically ```const Component = () => { return (<svg.../>)}```.  any fix for such ?  I get below error ```console.error
    Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.```

Comment: I dont have the preprocessor.js file in react testing library, how does it look like?

Answer (score 32):

Another easier option to solve this problem is `jest-svg-transformer`.

Just install it:
`npm i -D jest-svg-transformer` or `yarn add -D jest-svg-transformer`

And add to the `jest.config.js` to the transform's section:

```
"transform": {
   ...
   "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-svg-transformer"
}
```

Comment: This is several years later, but just a heads up for others that I tried this - but it was incompatible with the latest version of jest (v29)

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams Did you find any solution to the issue?

Comment: I ended up using jest-transform-stub as recommended by Maurice in another answer (though my final config was a bit different - review the documentation on how to configure it)

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams 2023, I followed this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/75969804/11483228 it basically mocked any svg files. This is perfectly fine for me. I don't need to test my svgs.

Answer (score 21):

Another option (not specific to React) is to use [`jest-transform-stub`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-transform-stub) since that will work for any non-JS file you want.

```json
{
  "jest": {
    // ..
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      ".+\\.(svg|css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The package actually does nothing but return an empty module.export. If you don't want to add a new dependency for this, I recommend Tom Pang's answer.

Answer (score 18):

While using `jest-svg-transformer`, for the setup I had it didn't work when placed under the `transformer` section. So I had to add it under `moduleNameMapper` and it worked.

```
yarn add jest-svg-transformer --dev
```

```
 moduleNameMapper: {
    "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-svg-transformer",
  }
```

Answer (score 14):

## SVG + Jest = Pain

When it comes to testing components with images, be prepared for a bit of pain.
Recently, I spent a whole day to understand how it works in Jest.

I understood the following:

- we can transform FILES with specific extensions (not components)
- we can transform all images as we like, but most often people transform images
  into the names of these images in order to get something like `<img src="image.svg" />` in the test
- jest don't understand non-js assets (without custom things)

### Problem

Let's describe an example that will return an error if we don't add an svg transformer to `jest.config.js`.
I will use [svg-jest](https://github.com/half-halt/svg-jest#svg-jest) library (I will describe it later with more details)

```js
import vectorUpImg from './assets/icons/vector-up.svg';

test('Renders svg as img src', () => {
  /* ... */
  render(<img src={vectorUpImg} />);
  /* ... */
});
```

The above example returns an error like:

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

>  7 | import vectorUpSvg from 'assets/icons/v2/plain/vector-up.svg';
```

OK. Let's add a custom transformer.
I will describe it later with more details, just know that the transformer will transform (lol)
our svg into a string like `vector-up.svg` and we'll get in the console:

```
 √ Renders svg as img src (55 ms)

  console.log
    <body>
      <div>
        <img
          src="vector-up.svg"
        />
      </div>
    </body>
```

Ok, test passed. But...
What if we want to use svg as component?

```js
import { ReactComponent as VectorUpComponent } from './assets/icons/vector-up.svg';

test('Renders svg as a ReactComponent. El by querySelector', () => {
  const { container } = render(<VectorUpComponent />);
  const svg = container.querySelector('svg');
  expect(svg).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

The above example returns an error like:

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) 
or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. 
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, 
or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

We can change the transformer
(not add another one because transformers are for file extensions, we can't add two different transformers for one ".svg" extension),
So now the transformer will parse the incoming content and create something like an svg module, so in our test we get:

```
√ Renders svg as a ReactComponent. El by querySelector (48 ms)

  console.log
    <body>
      <div>
        <svg
          data-jest-file-name="vector-up.svg"
          data-jest-svg-name="vector-up"
          data-testid="vector-up"
        />
      </div>
    </body>
```

Coooool, nuh? No... If we now try to pass svg to img src, we will get this:

```
 console.log
    <body>
      <div>
        <img
          src="[object Object]"
        />
      </div>
    </body>
```

Awful... But today I found the solution. [@ChromeQ](https://github.com/ChromeQ)
made a [fix](https://github.com/half-halt/svg-jest/pull/2) for the [svg-jest](https://github.com/half-halt/svg-jest)
library and now everything works fine, but you need to add some config until the owner of the
[svg-jest](https://github.com/half-halt/svg-jest) updates the package
or merges the PR by [@ChromeQ](https://github.com/ChromeQ) or [PR](https://github.com/half-halt/svg-jest/pull/4) by me.

So, lets workaround with this...

### My workaround

**My `jest.config.js`:**

```
 transform: {
    ...
    '^.+\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/src/tests/transformers/svg.js',
    ...
  },
```

Transformer `src/tests/transformers/svg.js`:

> I added the changes made by [@ChromeQ](https://github.com/ChromeQ), did a little refactoring, and added a few docs - [PR](https://github.com/half-halt/svg-jest/pull/4).

```js
const path = require('path');

/**
 * This function build module.
 *
 * Changes by https://github.com/ChromeQ:
 * - module.exports.default = ${functionName};
 * + module.exports.__esModule = true;
 * + module.exports.default = '${pathname}';
 *
 * Object props is a more extensible solution when we have a lot of props
 * @param {Object} props
 * @param {string} props.functionName
 * @param {string} props.pathname
 * @param {string} props.filename
 *
 * @function {(functionName, pathname, filename) => string} buildModule
 * @param {string} props
 * @return {string} string module
 */
const buildModule = props => {

  const {
    filename,
    functionName,
    pathname,
  } = props;

  return `
      const React = require('react');
      const ${functionName} = (props) =>
      {
      return React.createElement('svg', {
        ...props,
        'data-jest-file-name': '${pathname}',
        'data-jest-svg-name': '${filename}',
        'data-testid': '${filename}'
      });
      }
      module.exports.__esModule = true;
      module.exports.default = '${pathname}';
      module.exports.ReactComponent = ${functionName};
  `;
};

/**
 * This function creates a function name
 * @function {(base) => string} createFunctionName
 * @param {string} base
 * @return {string} string module
 */
const createFunctionName = base => {
  const words = base.split(/\W+/);
  /* here I refactored the code a bit and replaced "substr" (Deprecated) with "substring" */
  return words.reduce((identifier, word) => identifier + word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1), '');
};

/**
 * This function process incoming svg data
 * @function {(contents, filename) => string} processSvg
 * @param {string} contents - your svg. String like "<svg viewBox="..."><path d="..."/></svg>"
 * @param {string} filename - full path of your file
 * @return {string} string module
 */
const processSvg = (contents, filename) => {
  const parts = path.parse(filename);
  if (parts.ext.toLowerCase() === '.svg') {
    const functionName = createFunctionName(parts.name);
    return buildModule({
      filename: parts.name,
      functionName,
      pathname: parts.base,
    });
  }

  return contents;

  // for Jest28 it has to return an object with `code`
  // return { code: contents };
};

module.exports = { process: processSvg };
```

**My test:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, } from '@testing-library/react';
import vectorUpImg from './assets/icons/vector-up.svg';
import { ReactComponent as VectorUpComponent } from './assets/icons/vector-up.svg';

test('Renders svg as img src', () => {
  const { container } = render(<img src={vectorUpImg} />);
  const img = container.querySelector('img');
  expect(img).toBeInTheDocument();
  screen.debug();
});

test('Renders svg as a ReactComponent', () => {
  const label = 'icon-vector-up';
  const { getByLabelText } = render(<VectorUpComponent aria-label={label} />);
  expect(getByLabelText(label)).toBeInTheDocument();
  screen.debug();
});
```

**Console happily returns:**

```
  √ Renders svg as img src (46 ms)
  √ Renders svg as a ReactComponent (7 ms)

  console.log
    <body>
      <div>
        <img
          src="vector-up.svg"
        />
      </div>
    </body>

      at logDOM (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/pretty-dom.js:90:13)

  console.log
    <body>
      <div>
        <svg
          aria-label="icon-vector-up"
          data-jest-file-name="vector-up.svg"
          data-jest-svg-name="vector-up"
          data-testid="vector-up"
        />
      </div>
    </body>

      at logDOM (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/pretty-dom.js:90:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
```

### One more thing:

This library (as [described here](https://github.com/half-halt/svg-jest#svg-jest)) assigns some attributes:

> - *data-jest-file-name: The name of the file (e.g. 'some-image.svg')*
> - *data-jest-svg-name: Only the name portion of the file (e.g. 'some-image')*
> - *data-testid: Same as data-jest-svg-name, but works with @testing-library/react getByTestId()*

So if you want to find the rendered element in your test by attribute you have to pass in some other attributes.
In my example above, I passed the `aria-label` attribute and then found my svg at that label.
Or you can find it with `data-testid`, initialized by [svg-jest](https://github.com/half-halt/svg-jest#svg-jest) depends on your filename.
Or you can find it with `querySelector`, as in the example below:

```js
test('renders svg as a ReactComponent', () => {
  const { container } = render(<VectorUpComponent />);
  const svg = container.querySelector('svg');
  expect(svg).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: You're a star ! well done !

Comment: no need this works out of the box on cra https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/config/jest/fileTransform.js

Comment: This was very very use full. It should be the accepted answers. You save my day

Answer (score 7):

**Importing `*.svg` from `node_modules`?**

I had the same problem when importing `*.svg` files from an icon library in `node_modules`<sup>1</sup>. Using `jest-transform-stub` in the `"transform"` section of `jest.config.js` did not work for me, I had to use it in the `"moduleNameMapper"` section instead.

What helped for me was (in `jest.config.js`):

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+.(svg)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
  }
};
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The reason for this can be found in [`jest-transform-stub`'s README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-transform-stub).

> Jest doesn't apply transforms to node_modules by default. You can solve this by using moduleNameMapper.

Answer (score 4):

If you are still looking for a easy solution you can define your mock file as this

```
// svgMock.js
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

var Greeting = createReactClass({
  render: function() {
    return null;
  }
});
module.exports = Greeting;
```

Then in jest.config file do

```
{
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^.+\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/svgMock.js"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Depending on your project/linter configuration, a functional component such as the following may work too:
```
// svgMock.js
const MockSvgFile = (): JSX.Element => <></>;
export default MockSvgFile;
```

Comment: doing module.exports = 'div' is simpler

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who looking for a solution for Jest 28. This is an updated version of **Tom Pang**'s answer

**svgTransform.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    process(sourceText, sourcePath, options) {
        return {
            code: `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(path.basename(sourcePath))};`,
        };
    },
    getCacheKey() {
        return 'svgTransform';
    }
};
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
        "^.+\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/svgTransform.js",
    }
}
```

Ref. https://jestjs.io/docs/upgrading-to-jest28#transformer

Comment: Confirming this worked for me in Jest 29.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like the various out of the box transformers are no longer maintained for modern Jest versions.  I adapted one of them and simplified the code some.  Hope this helps someone out there.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const base64 = (filename, data) => {
  const type = filename.endsWith('.svg') ? 'svg+xml' : path.extname(filename).slice(1) || 'png';
  return `data:image/${type};base64,${data.toString('base64')}`;
};

module.exports = {
  getCacheKey: (_fileData, filename) => crypto.createHash('md5').update(filename).digest('hex'),
  process: (sourceText, filename) => `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(base64(filename, fs.readFileSync(filename)))};`,
};
```

Use this snippet to add it to the jest config transformers:

```js
'^.+\\.(svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$': '<rootDir>/test/imageTransformer.js',
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, even though a bit hacky with:
**Jest 29**
**2023**
**React & Vite**

was to do this:

```
// inside jest.config.json
 ...
 "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^.+\\.svg": "<rootDir>/tests/mocks/svgMock.jsx"
 }
 ...
```

The the mock file itself was a jsx file, with a div that just 'replaced' the svg files:

```
 // ./tests/mocks/svgMock.jsx

 import React from 'react';
 const SvgComponent = () => <div data-testid={'mock-svg'}></div>;
 export { SvgComponent };
```

The reason I used this setup was because I have one component that renders Icons and the export had to be with the exact name. Not pretty but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ts-jest`, you can just add `svg` to the transform list, on the `jest.config.js` or `jest.preset.js` file:

```
transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html|svg)$': 'ts-jest',
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who initialize project using CRA with TS, and React version is 17 or higher, use jest to run the test failed.

- you should add `.babelrc` in your rootDir as below:

```
// In order for the .babelrc file to take effect, you need to install babel-loader first.
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        // You don't need to import React after configured this
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/typescript"
  ]
}
```

- config jest in your `package.json` or `jest.config.js`, the config below is in `package.json`

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "transform": {
      "\\.[jt]sx?$": "babel-jest",
      ".+\\.(svg|css|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub"
    },
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
  }
```

- In my case, I use `jest` + `enzyme`, this is my `setupTests.js`

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Answer (score 0):

For the one coming with a higher version than jest@27

This is the new transformer you can use : [jest-transformer-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-transformer-svg)

Answer (score 0):

This code resolved the same issue, you can also use only SVG in the below code

//../jest.config.js

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': '<rootDir>/src/utils/file-mock.js',
    '^.+\\.(css|less|scss)$': 'babel-jest'
}


//../src/utils/file-mock.js
module.exports = 'stubbed-file';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is only one worked method for me was creating new functional components using [react-svgr](https://react-svgr.com/playground/)

1. Copy your svg code
2. Paste into the above site
3. Use new Сomponent instead of old  components

Answer (score 0):

You can create an SVG mock using `SVGR`. Just follow the instructions on this here [react-svgr jest config](https://react-svgr.com/docs/jest/)