# Check the render method of `InstanceImage` while testing using testing-library/react-native

Tags: react-native, redux, integration-testing, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a functional component with Redux using testing-library/react-native.

```
//InstanceImage.component.js
export default InstanceImage = (props) => {
  // <props init, code reduced >

  const { deviceId, instanceId } = DeviceUtils.parseDeviceInstanceId(deviceInstanceId)
  const deviceMap = useSelector(state => {
    return CommonUtils.returnDefaultOnUndefined((state) => {
      return state.deviceReducer.deviceMap
    }, state, {})
  })
  const device = deviceMap[deviceId]
  const instanceDetail = device.reported.instances[instanceId]
  if (device.desired.instances[instanceId] !== undefined) {
    return (
      <View
        height={height}
        width={width}
      >
        <ActivityIndicator
          testID={testID}
          size={loadingIconSize}
          color={fill}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
  const CardImage = ImageUtils[instanceDetail.instanceImage] === undefined ? ImageUtils.custom : ImageUtils[instanceDetail.instanceImage]

  return (
    <CardImage
      testID={testID}
      height={height}
      width={width}
      fill={fill}
      style={style}
    />
  )
}
```

And the test file is

```
//InstanceImage.component.test.js
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { color } from '../../../../src/utils/Color.utils';
import ConstantsUtils from '../../../../src/utils/Constants.utils';
import { default as Helper } from '../../../helpers/redux/device/UpdateDeviceInstanceIfLatestHelper';
import InstanceImage from '../../../../src/components/Switches/InstanceImage.component';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";
import TestConstants from '../../../../e2e/TestConstants';


const mockStore = configureMockStore();
const store = mockStore({
    deviceReducer: {
        deviceMap: Helper.getDeviceMap()
    }
});

const currentState = ConstantsUtils.constant.OFF

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    // styles init
  })
  
const props = {
    //props init
}

describe('Render InstanceImage', () => {
    it('InstanceImage renders correctly with values from props and Redux', () => {
        const rendered = render(<Provider store={store}>
            <InstanceImage {...props}/>
        </Provider>)

        const testComponent = rendered.getByTestId(TestConstants.icons.INSTANCE_IMAGE)
    });
})
```

And when I run the test file it gives the following error

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `InstanceImage`.
```

The component runs correctly when the app is run and there aren't any crashes. Still, this error occurs while performing tests.I am new to creating test cases for react native app so not able to debug this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found the error, the CardImage returns a custom svg image which was causing the issue. I used the `jest-svg-transformer` and it solved the issue.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63042067/4795837