# failing stencil unit test because of loading svg file

Tags: unit-testing, svg, jestjs, stenciljs, stencil-component

How can I change stencil.config.ts to support loading SVG files?

I have a logo component that loads an SVG and show it. I imported the logo svg like this:

```
import darkLogo from '../../assets/svgs/logo-dark.svg';
```

Then I used this SVG in my component:

```
render() {
    return (
       <div>
          <img src={ darkLogo }/>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

I added a unit test for this component in `logo-component.spec.ts` file to make sure the component is rendered correctly.

But after running tests, I received a synctax error because of loading SVG:

```
Details:

/app/assets/svgs/logo-dark.svg:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){<svg width="235" height="55" viewBox="0 0 235 55" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                                                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

  3 | } from '@stencil/core';
> 5 | import darkLogo from '../../assets/svgs/logo-dark.svg';
    | ^
```

I realised that stencil uses Jest library for testing. And Jest can not load SVG files. We need to add transformer for svg files to **jest.config.js** ([Jest cannot load svg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603201/jest-cannot-load-svg-file?rq=2)).
I do not use Jest directly, so I can not change the **jest.config.js**. I need to add custom configuration to **stencil.config.ts** in **testing** property (https://stenciljs.com/docs/testing-overview#testing-configuration):

```
import { Config } from '@stencil/core';

export const config: Config = {
  testing: {
    ...
  }
};
```

The question is: How can I change **stencil.config.ts** to support loading SVG files?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to solve it by:

1. Installing `jest-svg-transformer`

```bash
npm install -D jest-svg-transformer
```

2. Using transformer in `moduleNameMapper` setting in `stencil.config.ts`

```
testing: {
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx|css)$": "@stencil/core/testing/jest-preprocessor",
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-svg-transformer",
  },
}
```

Please inform if that helps.